# Optimize Mysql & My.cnf to 32g Ram & 8 Core CPU?

Tags: mysql

please , what is the best configuration to Innodb because mysql eat CPU on linux server
this is my configuration but I don`t sure it matches best solution

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size =24G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
join_buffer_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
thread_cache_size = 32
#max_allowed_packet = 1600M
max_allowed_packet = 100M
tmp_table_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=3G
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.